# My Google Script running off a google form is creating new columns in my Google Sheet on Entry

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my code:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}
function getLoc(value) {
  var destId = 
  FormApp.getActiveForm().getDestinationId();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destId);
  var respSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = respSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = data[0];
  var numColumns = headers.length;
  var numResponses = data.length;
  var c = value[0];
  var d = value[1];
  var e = c + "," + d;
  var lineNum = numResponses + 1;

  // Lets Rip through the headers and find the ones we are looking for
  for (let i = 0; i < numColumns; i++){
      if (headers[i].toLowerCase().trim() == "geoaddress"){
                respSheet.getRange(lineNum , i + 1).setValue("1");

      } else if (headers[i].toLowerCase().trim() == "geostamp"){
                respSheet.getRange(lineNum , i + 1).setValue("2");       

      } else if (headers[i].toLowerCase().trim() == "geocode"){
              respSheet.getRange(lineNum , i + 1).setValue("3");    

      } else if (headers[i].toLowerCase().trim() == "geolocation"){
              respSheet.getRange(lineNum , i + 1).setValue("4");
      }         
  }
}
```

I am attempting to write to 4 columns on a google sheet that is also collecting data for a form. When this executes, it is creating new columns rather than write to the existing ones. When I execute this in debug mode from the scripting editor, it properly writes to the appropriate columns but this isn't executing when the form is open. Anyone have any ideas? I think I have a conflict where the sheet is locked by the form or some such thing. Also, this is my first google scripting project... so, this may be a dumb question.

I have executed this in debug mode and with hard coded values. I am not especially well versed and so I am not sure what else to do.

Comment: Please simplify the [mcve] down to writing to the desired columns and nothing else.

Comment: Hey Cooper, thank you for responding. Those are the only columns I want. There are 4...The GeoLocation, GeoStamp, GeoCode and the Geo Address. These feilds are the ones not pasted in my google form.

Comment: Hey Cooper.. The more I looked at it, I can reduce it. Please see above.

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about a Geocoder and I doubt that the Geocoder is creating columns in your spreadsheet so please remove it and make another attempt to debug the problem yourself

Comment: Well it does the first time properly. The second it writes to duplicate columns next to the columns. So… that’s not the issue. In other words, the Geocoder works fine. It’s the writing to the google sheet that’s the problem.

Comment: Well then you should remove the Geocoder code from the [mcve] because it's not necessary.  The less code you have in the [mcve] the more likely someone will take the time to debug it and the more likely you will be able to debug it yourself which is the best solution of all.

Comment: I have removed the code that you suggested.

Comment: Single step through the script and figure out where the problem is